# Basic Fluent NHibernate relationship issue

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The project that I am working on at the moment is using Entity Framework, however there are some issues that we have come across and therefore I am researching using NHibernate which we believe will sort out the majority of issues we have.

Anyway, I have been replicating a simple part of the system, but I have ran into what I assume is a very simple problem with a one-to-many relationship as it is giving very strange results.

Here are my entities:

```
public class Task : Base.Domain
{
    private IList<TaskProperty> _taskProperties = new BindingList<taskProperty>();
    private string _name = String.Empty;
    private string _description = String.Empty;

    public virtual IList<TaskProperty> TaskProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return _taskProperties;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_taskProperties == value) return;
            _taskProperties = value;
            OnNotifiyPropertyChanged("TaskProperties");
        }
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) return;
            _name = value;
            base.OnNotifiyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public virtual string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_description == value) return;
            _description = value;
            base.OnNotifiyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    public Task() 
        : base()
    { }      
}

public class TaskProperty : Base.Domain
{
    private Task _task = null;
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    private string _description = string.Empty;
    private int _propertyType = 0;            

    //public virtual int TaskID { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task
    {
        get
        {
            return _task;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_task == value) return;
            _task = value;
            OnNotifiyPropertyChanged("Task");
        }
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) return;
            _name = value;
            OnNotifiyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public virtual string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_description == value) return;
            _description = value;
            OnNotifiyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    public virtual int PropertyType
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_propertyType == value) return;
            _propertyType = value;
            OnNotifiyPropertyChanged("PropertyType");
        }
    }

    public TaskProperty()
        : base()
    { }     
}
```

Here are my NHibernate mappings:

```
public class TaskMapping : ClassMap<Task>
{
    public TaskMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("RETTaskID");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.Version);
        HasMany(x => x.TaskProperties).KeyColumn("RETTaskPropertyID");
        Table("RETTask");
    }
}

public class TaskPropertyMapping : ClassMap<TaskProperty>
{
    public TaskPropertyMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("RETTaskPropertyID");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.PropertyType);
        References(x => x.Task).Column("RETTaskID");
        Table("RETTaskProperty");
    }
}
```

Note: The Domain class which these entities inherit from holds the ID (int Id).

The problem that I am facing is that when I get I Task from the database with an ID of 27 for example, I get the TaskProperty with an ID of 27 as well, not the expected 4 TaskProperties that are related to the Task via a foreign key.

This worked fine in Entity Framework and I know this is a simple situation for any ORM, so I assume I have set up my mappings incorrectly, but from all the examples I have found, I don't seem to be doing anything wrong!

Any answers/suggestions will be most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The Column mapping for HasMany and References must be the same:

```
public TaskMapping()
{
  ...
  HasMany(x => x.TaskProperties).KeyColumn("RETTaskID"); // use this
  // HasMany(x => x.TaskProperties).KeyColumn("RETTaskPropertyID"); // instead of this
}
public TaskPropertyMapping()
{
  ...
  References(x => x.Task).Column("RETTaskID");
}
```

The collection item has to have a reference column to the owner. This column is used for both directions, because that's how the reference in DB managed...

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested, but I still got the same issue. However I tried with `.KeyColumn("RETTaskID")` in both mapping classes and that worked. Seems to make sense, even though I didn't get it at first! Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, yeah ;) You are right, I edited the answer with fixed names. The essence is in the reuse of one column for both mappings.